# The regular expression construct \p{ name } is not working in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying the regular expression construct 
like \p{IsGreek} and \p{IsBasicLatin} 
but I am getting this error

> config/initializers/app_constants.rb:13: invalid character property
>   name {IsBasicLatin}

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Ruby does not support Unicode Blocks, but it does support Properties and Scripts. See [Character Properties on ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Character+Properties).

That means you can use the Unicode scripts:

- `\p{Latin}`
- `\p{Greek}`

For an introduction to Unicode Properties, Scripts and Blocks you can have a look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
\p{Greek}
\p{Latin}
```

Documentation here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.0 adds support for Unicode blocks:

```
$ ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -e "p /\p{InBasicLatin}/"
-e:1: invalid character property name {InBasicLatin}: /\p{InBasicLatin}/

$ ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -e "p /\p{InBasicLatin}/"
/\p{InBasicLatin}/
```

Note that you have to use `In`, not `Is`.